# Prioritisation of networking calls on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, urlsession

I want make use of good prioritisation of networking calls on iOS.

So far, I am using `URLSessionTask.priority`. I create networking calls like this:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    if let data = data, let response = response {
        // Handle response
    } else {
        // Handle error
    }
}
task.priority = priority
```

The problem is that I still see that download tasks with priority 0.0 take significant load (up to ~60%) from tasks with priority 1.0, as soon as they start. Sometimes, calls with a priority 1.0 only start when a larger number of low-priority requests completed. Apple's ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontask/1410569-priority)) confirms that:

> To provide hints to a host on how to prioritize URL session tasks from
>   your app, specify a priority for each task. Specifying a priority
>   provides only a hint and does not guarantee performance. [...]
>   There is no API to let you determine the effective priority for a task
>   from a host’s perspective.

**I want to implement presumptive downloading and caching, without reducing the performance of user initiated requests.** This is especially important on devices with poor connectivity.

Solutions I have considered:

- Using Alamofire (but afaik they don’t have prioritisation either)
- Create a custom solution that would only allow `n` parallel downloads, have a priority queue, and abort/pause very low priority requests when high priority requests come in. To me, though, this sounds like something that must exist already, and also a bit like a fantastic way to shoot myself in the foot, if implemented wrongly.

Alternatives I considered:

- Only start less important calls after the most important calls are done
- Don’t do the requests at all on bad connections (follow up question would be how to identify a bad connection)

I am supporting iOS 9 and newer, but would also consider solutions that don't work on iOS 9.

Comment: What do u mean by "tasks with priority 0.0 completely block tasks with priority 1.0 " Are u running tasks on a serialized queue ? By default NSURLSession allows u to run multiple data tasks at a time. So even if low priority tasks start they should run in parallel and not block high priority ones. You can always set HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost to fix the max number of concurrent connection u can open to host

Comment: I would be good to see all the code. there might me something with the calls you are making and setting the priority

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Fair point, I clarified the question a bit. From my point of view, in an ideal solution, a high priority request would get the majority of networking capacity available, even when there are several low priority requests progressing.
I have not yet set `httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost` because I was afraid that it would reduce performance on good connectivity, and it only works if there are a lot of connections to a single host.

Comment: @hariszaman I doubt that this is a code-related problem, but I'll try to create a sample project to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @sebastian-hojas : I agree setting httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost might affect the performance in good connectivity scenarios. As far as task priority is concerned Doc clearly says "Specifying a priority provides only a hint and does not guarantee performance" refer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontask/1410569-priority. That being said, If you have to achieve this capability of selective download, I afraid U'll end up creating a custom mechanism of ur own as u happened to mention in ur question :o I'll keep my eye on this question quite interesting one :) hence +1

Comment: I just stumbled over this... and I just can't believe that there isn't a "ready to use" solution for that problem. Neither Apple nor the Community (GitHub, Pods, etc.) seem to have a solution for that -.-
So, is it too hard (or maybe too easy 0_o) to build a lib/framework for that? Or does just no-one really need this? (I would need it^^)

Comment: in 2021 did anyone find solution ?, I see similar UX in youtube app where in bad connectivity my video plays perfect but failed to load comments of that video :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As apple mention in the documentation, the priority field is just a hint, and not really a guarantee of how ressources are going to be spent.

For more tight enforcement of network priorities; as you mentioned, the only possibility is to limit the number of concurrent requests. This is actually what Alamofire image caching library is doing

Alamofire does not support priority outside of setting the NSURLSessionTask priority value.